In QGIS, is there a way to plot (by colour) the proximity of a polygon to another polygon of a different shapefile?
I am trying to produce a map to show the proximity of administrative areas to parks. I'd like to show this in terms of how many other administrative areas are between a given area and the nearest park (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4... areas) and show this in a colour scale, similar to the example image shown below (this shows these parks overlain on a colour map of a different metric).
I have a shapefile of these administrative areas and parks.
Do you have any ideas of how this could be done?

